# How to merge mdi parent child toolstrip?

Tags: c#, mdi, toolstrip

How can i find toolstrip1 control on child form.
This does not work:

```
    private void EUF_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripManager.Merge(this.ActiveMdiChild.Controls("toolStrip1"), toolStrip1);
    }
```

I get an error :

```
     Error  1   
     Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls' cannot be used like a method.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
ToolStripManager.Merge((ToolStrip)this.ActiveMdiChild.Controls["toolStrip1"] , toolStrip1);
```

I think you're from VB background which uses `()` syntax for Indexing where as c# uses `[]`. And your code doesn't work because `()` is used for method call and compiler assumes you're trying to call a method which doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

`Controls` isn't a function; it's a property that returns a type with an indexer.

You need to write `Controls[...]`.